# How to join two queries where both have COUNT and grouping without headache?

Tags: mysql, join, union

I've been trying to join results from two queries in one table to count them and sort in hours.

I have tried `SELECT` and `UNION ALL`, but no luck.
I've searched all StackOverflow and google, but running all the time in headaches.
If i run my query single - all is good and i'm getting my output.

Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as peopleCount, date_format( timestamp, '%H' ) as hours 
FROM unknownCheckin
WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-01 23' and eid = '222' 
GROUP BY hours 
order by timestamp ASC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as peopleCount, date_format( timestamp, '%H' ) as hours
FROM checkin 
WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-01 23' and eid = '222' 
GROUP BY hours 
order by timestamp ASC
```

My experiment was:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as peopleCount, date_format( timestamp, '%H' ) as hours FROM unknownCheckin
INNER JOIN checkin
ON unknownCheckin.eid = checkin.eid
WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-01 23' and eid = '222' 
GROUP BY hours order by timestamp ASC
```

## 1052 - Column 'timestamp' in field list is ambiguous

Expected Result if running single query1:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| peopleCount    | hours                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4              | 21                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1              | 22                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1              | 00                            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Query 2:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| peopleCount    | hours                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 10             | 22                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22             | 23                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 12             | 00                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5              | 01                            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

What i want to see is:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| peopleCount    | hours                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4              | 21                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 11             | 22                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22             | 23                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 13             | 00                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5              | 01                            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Sorry, i'm out of thinking power.
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use a union here:

```
SELECT
    hours,
    COUNT(*) as peopleCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H') AS hours
    FROM unknownCheckin
    WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-01 23' AND eid = '222'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H')
    FROM checkin
    WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-01 23' AND eid = '222'
) t
GROUP BY hours
ORDER BY -FIELD(hours, '23', '22');
```

Comment: Wow! That was really fast and flawless.
Now i'm just trying to show them in proper order
22 / 23 / 00 / 01

now i have - 00 / 01 / 23 
makes sense that it threats it as digit, not as time...

Comment: '%a %H' was the best outcome <3

Comment: @IESPOTO I have given you an option to sort the way you expect.

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question, if for no other reason that many more people will have a look at it.  Unless, you have some very small follow-up related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

UNION for the 2 queries and then get the sum of peopleCount:

```
select 
  t.hours,
  sum(t.peopleCount) peopleCount
from (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as peopleCount, date_format( timestamp, '%H' ) as hours 
  FROM unknownCheckin
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-01 23' and eid = '222' 
  GROUP BY hours 
  union all
  SELECT COUNT(*) as peopleCount, date_format( timestamp, '%H' ) as hours
  FROM checkin 
  WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-01 23' and eid = '222' 
  GROUP BY hours 
) t
group by t.hours
```

Comment: Thanks to you too! This is also working perfectly :)